# getting screen width and height of the screen

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x

I'm trying to get window size, but I'm getting the wrong position.

I'm getting the size with this:

```
Size visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getWinSize();
```

But, when I try to use visibleSize.width/2 and .height/2 the sprite doesn't appear in the center of the screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try explicitly setting the anchor point of the sprite to the middle of the sprite.

`sprite->setAnchorPoint(Point(0.5, 0.5))`

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Coordinate_System